# move folder from one local disk to another

Tags: php, directory, rename

To move folder "aze" to folder "log" and rename it "qsd" in the same local disk, I used :

`rename("rename/aze", "D:/log/qsd");`

But When I try to move to "C:/test/uploads/qsd" It doesn't work :

`rename("rename/aze", "C:/test/uploads/qsd");`

My server is in "D" disk.

Comment: php does not have access to local files. Upload the file to server and then you can move it within your server

Comment: But in my case I move the folder out of the server.

Comment: that is why it doesn't work ;)

Comment: But It works. the folder aze is in www/ and I move it to log/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible, so I copy the folder in the destination path and then, delete it in the source path.